# Data repeated (rather than duplicate)

Tags: php, mysql, repeat, duplicates

I'm having a problem with repeated (rather than 'duplicate') entries in my tables.

Firstly, let me explain the scenario.  I have a Windows based machine on our network acting as an apache server running PHP and MYSQL.

Using various browsers (but usually Chrome) any of my 30+ users can log in and access my PHP program(routines).

Now for an example.  I have a table that has "certno" as a unique column, and other columns such as 'manuf','model','serial','desc'  etc
A user enters the data for the "other" columns into a web form. When submitted my program inserts a new row into the table with 'certno' being an increment from the previous row.

The problem is that occasionally I notice duplicate entries; different 'certno' values obviously but with the data duplicated.  Time stamps show these enteries to be just a few seconds apart; insufficient time for the user to enter the data again.

Investigation indicates that a possible cause is that a network delay prevents the client browser from knowing that the entry was successful and it submits the data again.

Is this a possible cause or can someone suggest something else?
Any suggestions to prevent this from happening would also be appreciated.
Note that I'm not (yet) using START TRANSACTION and COMMIT.  Would this make any difference if it's a network delay issue?

Comment: I suggest you to make some of those fields UNIQUE, this way it cannot be "repeated" anymore.

Comment: you can do a check if the data was entered in the last 10sec

Answer (score 0):

you could generate a unique id on form generation, eg (inline php for brevity):

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo uniqid();?>">
```

And have that field as unique in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If you have at least a column which is logically unique, then add a unique constraint to that. Example:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_PersonID UNIQUE (P_Id,LastName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get):

> instead of returning a web page directly, the POST operation returns a redirection command. The HTTP 1.1 specification introduced the HTTP 303 ("See other") response code to ensure that in this situation, the web user's browser can safely refresh the server response without causing the initial HTTP POST request to be resubmitted.